# fill high data in wxListCtrl using wxThread- i can but 

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

i want to fill database table in wxListCtrl, i can do this , i m using wxThread for this. my problem is - my concept is working for small amount of data, when i increase the size, it shows a error like-

```
showingdatainwxlistctrl: ../../src/XlibInt.c:595: _XPrivSyncFunction: Assertion `dpy->synchandler == _XPrivSyncFunction' failed.
```

my code is given below:-

```
void *MyThread :: Entry()
{
    int i=1,j,k=0   ;
    while(i!=400)
    {
        long index=this->temp->data_list_control->InsertItem(i,wxT("amit"));

        for(j=1;j<3;j++)
        {
            this->temp->data_list_control->SetItem(index,j,wxT("pathak"));    
        }
        k++;
        if(k==30)
        {
            this->Sleep(1000);
            k=0;
        }
        i++;    
    }
}
```

if i used i =4, 10 100, it is working but i crossed the limit( i dont know at which point) it start showing error
if you have any suggestion then pls help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of direct SetItem call from the worker thread, you need to post event to the main thread and add item in the event handler. Data for list control event should be placed to custom event class. See details in wxPostEvent function and here: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Custom_Events

Comment: you mean to say in thread class we get the value to be filled and passed to main thread( from where the thread called) there i should use setItem for filling wxListCtrl value.. i tried this a lot but how i can post event to send the data and how to get the data in main thread

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing a non-threadsafe wxListCtrl from another thread, this will simply not work.

A better solution may be to skip the thread, use a wxTimer, then fill 400 more entries every time OnTimer is called.